# query string error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a problem in query.

Error is: {"Invalid column name 'TotalRecords'."}

I have a table named upload_news in this table there many records and I want retrieve data by country wise where in the distinct countries greater than 20 records.

```
select count(Distinct country) AS TotalRecords, country from upload_news where TotalRecords > 20";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Group By and Having:

```
select count(Distinct country) AS TotalRecords, country from upload_news 
group by country
having count(Distinct country) > 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
"SELECT *
FROM
(
select count(Distinct country) AS TotalRecords, country from upload_news 
group by country
) T
where TotalRecords > 20";
```

because **TotalRecords** *alias* column, you can't access it directly.

Comment: {"Column 'upload_news.country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."}